# Can't fetch latest data from mongodb using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb

I have a collection on mongodb & I am trying to fetch latest 20 data from my collection using ajax. here is my code,

```
$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/obs/collections/udatas?apiKey=myapikey",
}).done(function(data)
```

This code returns first 1000 data. I have more then 1800 data on my collection.
So, how can I get my last 20 data using ajax?

Comment: What has jQuery to do with the way the API works? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [documentation](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#list-documents)

this is guide:

```
[&s=<order>][&sk=<skip>][&l=<limit>]
```

and fixed:

```
$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/obs/collections/udatas?apiKey=myapikey&sk=1780&l=20",
}).done(function(data)
```